# Remote host said: 550 5.7.1 message content rejected

Tags: postfix, email, email-bounces, spamassassin

A sender from France is trying to send an email to us. Unfortunately his email is being rejected with the message below.  I suspect there are some weird characters in the mail content but how can I allow the content to be accepted in our mail server. Thanks

```
-----Message d'origine-----

De : postmaster@somedomain.fr [mailto:postmaster@somedomain.fr]

Envoyé : lundi 16 septembre 2013 11:18

À : pl.pl  
Objet : failure notice


Hi. This is the qmail-send program at somedomain.fr.

I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.

This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.



<destemail@destdomain.nl>:

194.xx.xx.xx failed after I sent the message.

Remote host said: 550 5.7.1 message content rejected



<booking@destdomain.nl>:

194.xx.xx.xx failed after I sent the message.

Remote host said: 550 5.7.1 message content rejected



--- Below this line is a copy of the message.



Return-Path: <pl.pl@somedomain.fr>

Received: (qmail 3621 invoked from network); 16 Sep 2013 11:17:20 +0200

Received: from pl.pl@somedomain.fr by mailhost by uid 64011 with qmail-scanner-1.22

 (spamassassin: 3.1.7-deb.  Clear:RC:1(10.8.6.44):.

 XProcessed in 0.287702 secs);

Received: from unknown (HELO cordelia.ad2003.intra) (10.8.6.44)

  by mailhost.vvf-vacances.fr with SMTP; 16 Sep 2013 11:17:19 +0200

X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft Exchange V6.5

Content-class: urn:content-classes:message

MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: multipart/mixed;

      boundary="----_=_NextPart_001_01CEB2BD.6EE00PEE2"

Subject: stop sales somedomain clubs-w14-Tignes from 19.04 to 26.04.14-u2u4u5-130916

Date: Mon, 16 Sep 2013 11:16:16 +0200

Message-ID: <DA9EFBC2DAE173483234EE12HJAWH333KLJHJEE@cordelia.ad2003.intra>

X-MS-Has-Attach:

X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:

Thread-Topic: this sub somedomain clubs-w14-Tignes from 19.04 to 26.04.14-u2u4u5-130916

Thread-Index: Ac6yvWWB123HJK12ysajhufZqu3Q==

X-Priority: 1

Priority: Urgent

Importance: high

From: "pl pl" <pl.pl@somedomain.fr>
```

**Logs**

```
cleanup[10347]: 298D65EA1F7: reject: header To: <teresa.otano@turintia.com>,??<ased@serapea.it>,??"Lemestre cmm" <cmm.Lemestre@frenchhost.fr>,??<jitka.grva@cedok.cz>,??<partenaire@octopode.fr>,??<michal.sky@europe-mountains.c from mailhost.vvf-vcs.fr[217.109.xx.xx]; from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr> to=<stopsales@mydomain.nl> proto=SMTP helo=<mailhost.frenchhost.fr>: 5.7.1 message content rejected/cleanup[10347]: 298D65EA1F7: reject: header To: <tt.otano@turintia.com>,??<ased@serapea.it>,??"Lemestre cmm" <cmm.Lemestre@frenchhost.fr>,??<jitka.grva@cedok.cz>,??<partenaire@octopode.fr>,??<michal.sky@europe-mountains.c from mailhost.vvf-vcs.fr[217.109.xx.xx]; from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr> to=<stopsales@mydomain.nl> proto=SMTP helo=<mailhost.frenchhost.fr>: 5.7.1 message content rejected
cleanup[10347]: 298D65EA1F7: reject: header To: <teresa.otano@turintia.com>,??<ased@serapea.it>,??"Lemestre cmm" <cmm.Lemestre@frenchhost.fr>,??<jitka.grva@cedok.cz>,??<partenaire@octopode.fr>,??<michal.sky@europe-mountains.c from mailhost.vvf-vcs.fr[217.109.xx.xx]; from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr> to=<stopsales@mydomain.nl> proto=SMTP helo=<mailhost.frenchhost.fr>: 5.7.1 message content rejected/cleanup[10334]: DD9AD5EA1F7: reject: header To: <tt.otano@turintia.com>,??<ased@serapea.it>,??"Lemestre cmm" <cmm.Lemestre@frenchhost.fr>,??<jitka.grva@cedok.cz>,??<partenaire@octopode.fr>,??<michal.sky@europe-mountains.c from mailhost.vvf-vcs.fr[217.109.xx.xx]; from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr> to=<booking@mydomain.nl> proto=SMTP helo=<mailhost.frenchhost.fr>: 5.7.1 message content rejected
Sep 16 11:18:48 mail postfix/cleanup[18159]: C70495EA0A7: reject: header To: <tt.otano@turintia.com>,??<ased@serapea.it>,??"Lemestre cmm" <cmm.Lemestre@frenchhost.fr>,??<jitka.grva@cedok.cz>,??<partenaire@octopode.fr>,??<michal.sky@europe-mountains.c from mailhost.vvf-vcs.fr[217.109.xx.xx]; from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr> to=<stopsales@mydomain.nl> proto=SMTP helo=<mailhost.frenchhost.fr>: 5.7.1 message content rejected
Sep 16 11:18:49 mail postfix/cleanup[18651]: 150225EA1F3: reject: header To: <tt.otano@turintia.com>,??<ased@serapea.it>,??"Lemestre cmm" <cmm.Lemestre@frenchhost.fr>,??<jitka.grva@cedok.cz>,??<partenaire@octopode.fr>,??<michal.sky@europe-mountains.c from mailhost.vvf-vcs.fr[217.109.xx.xx]; from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr> to=<booking@mydomain.nl> proto=SMTP helo=<mailhost.frenchhost.fr>: 5.7.1 message content rejected
Sep 16 11:41:37 mail postfix/qmgr[1592]: 39D995EA0A7: from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, size=74553, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 16 11:41:38 mail postfix/qmgr[1592]: CAD155EA1E2: from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, size=74551, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 16 11:41:42 mail postfix/qmgr[1592]: 763D55EA1F3: from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, size=74965, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 16 11:41:42 mail amavis[23427]: (23427-08) Passed CLEAN, [217.109.xx.xx] [217.109.xx.xx] <pl.pl@frenchhost.fr> -> <stopsales@mydomain.nl>, Message-ID: <DA9EFBC2DAE1734883610A6D082EE8AF0C8263FA@cordelia.ad2003.intra>, mail_id: fVpqXVSHvR8g, Hits: -1.888, size: 74553, queued_as: 763D55EA1F3, 4931 ms
Sep 16 11:41:42 mail postfix/qmgr[1592]: 814795EA1F4: from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, size=74959, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 16 11:41:42 mail amavis[23431]: (23431-09) Passed CLEAN, [217.109.xx.xx] [217.109.xx.xx] <pl.pl@frenchhost.fr> -> <booking@mydomain.nl>, Message-ID: <DA9EFBC2DAE1734883610A6D082EE8AF0C8263FA@cordelia.ad2003.intra>, mail_id: fM9aP-Xn5t2d, Hits: -1.888, size: 74551, queued_as: 814795EA1F4, 4280 ms
Sep 16 11:41:42 mail postfix/qmgr[1592]: 9E2A75EA0A7: from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, size=75102, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 16 11:41:43 mail postfix/qmgr[1592]: CDB875EA1E2: from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, size=75110, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 16 11:45:45 mail amavis[23431]: (23431-15-2) Passed CLEAN, [10.10.24.34] [10.10.24.34] <stopsales@mydomain.nl> -> <pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, Message-ID: <5236D2D3.1070704@mydomain.nl>, mail_id: FdL4-ZMMUBOK, Hits: -2.176, size: 9718, queued_as: 9DA385EA1FD, 1831 ms
Sep 16 11:45:45 mail postfix/smtp[27048]: 7774B5EA1F4: to=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, conn_use=2, delay=2.2, delays=0.39/0/0/1.8, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok, id=23431-15-2, from MTA([127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 9DA385EA1FD)
Sep 16 11:45:50 mail postfix/smtp[24952]: 9DA385EA1FD: to=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, relay=mailhost.frenchhost.fr[217.109.xx.xx]:25, delay=4.7, delays=0.06/0/0.11/4.6, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok 1379324669 qp 7811)
Sep 16 11:56:40 mail postfix/qmgr[1592]: E30BD5EA1E2: from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, size=76659, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 16 11:56:41 mail postfix/qmgr[1592]: B0C185EA1E9: from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, size=76657, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 16 11:56:45 mail postfix/qmgr[1592]: 8EABF5EA1F3: from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, size=77071, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 16 11:56:45 mail amavis[27641]: (27641-12) Passed CLEAN, [217.109.xx.xx] [217.109.xx.xx] <pl.pl@frenchhost.fr> -> <stopsales@mydomain.nl>, Message-ID: <DA9EFBC2DAE1734883610A6D082EE8AF0C8263FB@cordelia.ad2003.intra>, mail_id: fSNON0h82SkH, Hits: -1.888, size: 76658, queued_as: 8EABF5EA1F3, 4976 ms
Sep 16 11:56:45 mail postfix/qmgr[1592]: D65055EA1E2: from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, size=77216, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 16 11:56:46 mail postfix/qmgr[1592]: 8BA8B5EA1E2: from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, size=77065, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 16 11:56:46 mail amavis[29173]: (29173-05) Passed CLEAN, [217.109.xx.xx] [217.109.xx.xx] <pl.pl@frenchhost.fr> -> <booking@mydomain.nl>, Message-ID: <DA9EFBC2DAE1734883610A6D082EE8AF0C8263FB@cordelia.ad2003.intra>, mail_id: O0lKAyyLZK5v, Hits: -1.888, size: 76656, queued_as: 8BA8B5EA1E2, 5241 ms
Sep 16 11:56:46 mail postfix/qmgr[1592]: A81905EA1F3: from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, size=77208, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 16 12:00:49 mail amavis[30799]: (30799-01) Passed CLEAN, [10.10.24.34] [10.10.24.34] <stopsales@mydomain.nl> -> <pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, Message-ID: <5236D657.5080608@mydomain.nl>, mail_id: p0XSEn61skVD, Hits: -2.176, size: 9720, queued_as: 8AB0F5EA1F4, 4948 ms
Sep 16 12:00:49 mail postfix/smtp[30803]: C95A95EA1E9: to=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=5.9, delays=0.9/0/0.01/4.9, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok, id=30799-01, from MTA([127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 8AB0F5EA1F4)
Sep 16 12:00:56 mail postfix/smtp[29721]: 8AB0F5EA1F4: to=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr>, relay=mailhost.frenchhost.fr[217.109.xx.xx]:25, delay=7.1, delays=0.1/0/0.26/6.7, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok 1379325575 qp 10180)
```

Comment: What kind of MTA are you using? Does the message contain some attachments?

Comment: qmail, message rejected by qmail-scanner

Comment: @ALex_hha It is postfix.  I've included the tag in the question.

Comment: Where is mail log from your postfix?

Comment: @ALex_hha I have attached the logs. I've done some changes in the logs to protect privcacy of some people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a relevant log entry:

```
Sep 16 11:18:49 mail postfix/cleanup[18651]: 150225EA1F3: reject: header To: <tt.otano@turintia.com>,??<ased@serapea.it>,??"Lemestre cmm" <cmm.Lemestre@frenchhost.fr>,??<jitka.grva@cedok.cz>,??<partenaire@octopode.fr>,??<michal.sky@europe-mountains.c from mailhost.vvf-vcs.fr[217.109.xx.xx]; from=<pl.pl@frenchhost.fr> to=<booking@mydomain.nl> proto=SMTP helo=<mailhost.frenchhost.fr>: 5.7.1 message content rejected
```

As you can see, it refers to the email `To:` header, and there are invalid characters in that header.

Your sender should check his mail program and ensure that it is constructing email headers properly.

Comment: I think I forgot to thank you.  It indeed was the senders client. All sorted.